# What do we mean by "a double" when we throw two dice?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In my practical assignment, I have this question.

> Roll two dice and let:
>
> $A:$ sum of $7$;
>
> $B:$ a double;
>
> Are these two events mutually exclusive?

I can do this part but I am not sure what "a double" means.

What I think it means:

- $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)$. But as far as I know this is called a "doublet".
- $(1,2),(2,4),(3,6)$ One face is the double of the other.

So someone please tell me what it could be.

Comment: The almost certainly mean that the two faces coincide.  I've never heard the word "doublet".

Comment: The first one ... which also includes (6,6) btw

Comment: Really @lulu  ?  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doublet   on the second definition A pair of two similar or equal things; couple.

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks.

Comment: @Isham  Oh, I didn't mean to suggest that nobody has ever used the term.  Just that I have never heard it.  And I play a lot of games with dice.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean @lulu

Comment: In many games it's called "doubles" rather than "doublet." Just different terminology for the same thing.

Comment: alternatively, is there an elegant word to describe two dice (or numbers) that do not match? in compressing the rules of a game i’m seeking terms, heh. edit: i guess “singles” is a fine word possibly, with doubles defined (lol, singlets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answerers have pointed out, a double means that both dice show the same number.  "Doublet" or "doublets" is a synonym, see the fifth definition [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/doublet), or the third definition [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doublets).  Hence the doubles are (in your notation) $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,3)$, $(4,4)$, $(5,5)$, $(6,6)$.  You can readily see that these six results have sums $2$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $10$, and $12$, respectively, none of which is 7.  Hence the events `a sum of 7` and `doubles` are mutually exclusive.

As an extension of this idea (because I feel that a good answer should give you something else to think about), suppose that you have an $n$-sided die.  Let $A$ and $B$ be the events
$$ A = (\text{the die sum to 7})
\qquad\text{and}\qquad B = (\text{doubles, i.e. both dice show the same number}). $$
Are these two events mutually exclusive?  What if we allow the dice to be numbered differently.  For example, instead of numbering the die from 1 to $n$, what if we number them from $-n$ to $n$?  Are `doubles` and `sums to 7` still mutually exclusive?  What if we don't require the numbers to be sequential?  What if we don't require the numbering to be integers, but allow any real number?  Are the events `doubles` and `sums to 7` still mutually exclusive?

Comment: I think it will be mutually exclusive because there is no way we can get sum 7 from doublets.ohh wait real numbers too. let me think again .

Comment: One instace will be 3.5 one both die. Then it wont be M.E.

Comment: @Damn1o1 Bingo! :)  Nicely reasoned.

Comment: Thanks for putting up the question. I felt like i am getting interviewed :D.

Comment: 1 + 1 = 2 - I'd edit but it would have to be six characters.

Comment: @tilde Ha!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely impossible to know exactly what the author meant. But it seems to me like a relatively safe assumption that they meant that the two dice show the same result.

"But as far as I know its called doublet." And I usually call it a pair. Many things have several different names. That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the same number on both dice.